# Rails nested form on show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I am trying to add addresses to a company with nested forms on the company#show page. I am successful in adding the new address, but when the page reloads, the form area for the new address is populated with the existing records.

How am I able to show only the empty built record and not the existing records?

This is what shows up in the form area...

[image]

This is what I am expecting...

[image]

Here is the company#show page...

```
= form_for @company do |f|
  = f.fields_for :addresses do |t|
    .form-inline
      .col-md-2
        = t.text_field :street1, class: 'form-control form-control-sm', placeholder: 'Street 1', id: 'street1'
      .col-md-2
        = t.text_field :street2, class: 'form-control form-control-sm', placeholder: 'Street 2', id: 'street2'
      .col-md-2
        = t.text_field :apt_other, class: 'form-control form-control-sm', placeholder: 'Suite #', id: 'apt_other'
      .col-md-2
        = t.text_field :city, class: 'form-control form-control-sm', placeholder: 'City', id: 'city'
      .col-md-1
        = t.collection_select :state_id, @states, :id, :state_abbr, {:include_blank => 'State'} , {:class => 'form-control form-control-sm'}
      .col-md-2
        = t.text_field :zip, class: 'form-control form-control-sm', placeholder: 'Zip', id: 'zip'
    .form-inline
      .col-md-2
        = t.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control form-control-sm', placeholder: 'Phone', id: 'phone'
      .col-md-2
        = t.text_field :fax, class: 'form-control form-control-sm', placeholder: 'Fax', id: 'fax'
  .form-group-row
    .text-center
      .btn-group{role: 'group'}
        = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-outline-success btn-sm', style: 'margin-bottom: .5em;'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer it to close the thread.

This line was wrong.

```
= f.fields_for :addresses do |t|
```

This is is what I changed it to.

```
= f.fields_for :addresses, Address.new do |t|
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that to be separated you would need to either add a check or condition to only show non-persisted addresses in the fields_for or you need to initialize a new address in your controller and show a form only for that one. For example:

```
#companies_controller.rb
...
def show
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  @new_address = @company.addresses.build()
end
...
```

And then instead of showing the `fields_for :addresses` you should just create a `form_for @new_address`

I think you can also pass the `@new_address` directly into the `fields_for` like so:

`= f.fields_for :addresses, @new_address do |t|`

I haven't tested this, you might need to write this as an array `[@new_address]`. What this basically does is that it forces a specific collection of objects to be used for the nested `fields_for`. You can also read the [docs on fields_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).